# Postgresql are not accepting insert statements - just timing out

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-12

Apparently my PSQL 12 stopped working from one moment to the other.

Not accepting any insert statements anymore, while select statements for perfectly fine.

```
psql (12.11 (Ubuntu 12.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

cfoo=> \dt
cfoo=> select * from django_session;
cfoo=> \d django_session;
                  Table "public.django_session"
Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 session_key  | character varying(40)    |           | not null | 
 session_data | text                     |           | not null | 
 expire_date  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "django_session_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (session_key)
    "django_session_expire_date_a5c62663" btree (expire_date)
    "django_session_session_key_c0390e0f_like" btree (session_key varchar_pattern_ops)

cfoo=> select * from django_session;
cfoo=> insert into django_session (session_key, session_data, expire_date) values ('123', '123', '2021-12-18 18:01:44.119+01');
```

And then nothing. No error, no timeout. Just staying like this.
This is the master and the slave is also not replicating right now. Not sure this is related, as I uncommented the config for that in the pg_hbl.conf already and restarted.

Any clues?

Comment: Check the state of the sessions in the view `pg_stat_activity` - your PSQL session is most likely waiting for a lock. Some other transaction/session already inserted a row with that session_key but did not commit it, or it was deleted by that was not committed.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, that the streaming replication was still active and had to be removed at several places including postgresql.conf.

Postgresql was waiting for the replication to happen and therefor locked the insert.